Barcode doesn't get replaced if it is called again without closing program on Python
def Ticket_Register_Car(self):
        if(self.isTicketControl):
            numBarCode = str(self.registro[0]).zfill(7)
            print("Num:", numBarCode)
            
            if not os.path.exists('settings/ticketBarcode.png'):
                print('Se supone que no existe')
                # Selecciona el tipo de código de barras que deseas generar, en este caso 'ean8'
                hr = get_barcode_class('ean8')
                # Genera el código de barras
                barcode = hr(numBarCode, writer=ImageWriter())
                # Guarda el código de barras en un archivo
                barcode.save('settings/ticketBarcode')
            else:
                absPath = os.path.abspath('settings/ticketBarcode.png')
                absPath = absPath.replace('.png', '')
                print("Ruta sin el png: " + absPath)
                hr = get_barcode_class('ean8')
                barcode = hr(numBarCode, writer=ImageWriter())
                barcode.save(absPath)
                print('Se supone que se borró')

            self.obj.Imprimir_Ticket_Cliente()

I'm making a GUI that print tickets but the problem is that the first time the Ticket_Register_Car is called and the path does exist it enters in the ELSE and replace the png file and the ticket is printed but if I call that function again without closing the app and it's still ELSE the png file is not replaced and consequently the ticket is not printed.
I made the printing functions with C# and I'm usign Pyhtonnet to run C# code.
I tried to use the absolute path but it doesn't work. I tried if the PNG file exists deleting the image and create a new one but it doesn't work neither.

Is file getting saved with the png extension?  Try : barcode.save('settings/ticketBarcode.png')

Thanks but that will make the png file be named as: 'ticketBarcode.png.png'.
It is not saved with the '.png' extension because it is saved like that by deafult.

Are you sure!!!  Set file explorer to view extensions and then look at the file that is saved.   You are saving using 'settings/ticketBarcode' then reading using 'settings/ticketBarcode.png'

Because the code saves it as png and put png to the code just will make the file name be called as ticketBarcode.png.png, twice
